# ipython: %paste over ssh connection

Tags: ipython

In ipython >=0.11, the %paste command is required to paste indented commands.  However, if I run an ipython shell in a remote terminal, the buffer %paste refers to is on the remote machine rather than the local machine.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: I've just remembered there's the `%cpaste` magic as well. That gives you space to paste in, and you can simply add `--` on a line to stop and run the code you've pasted.

Comment: Please switch the answer to `%cpaste`, that's the better solution.  Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think this is exactly what `%cpaste` is for (I am always forgetting about all the things IPython does).  `%cpaste` enters a state allowing you to paste already formatted or indented code, and it will strip leading indentation and prompts, so you can copy/paste indented code from files, or even from an interactive Python session including leading `>>>` or `In [1]` which will be stripped.

Comment: does `%cpaste` pull from the local or remote buffer?

Comment: local (to the user, not to IPython). `%cpaste` enters a mode that prevents all the autoindent, etc. stuff, so that regular pasting of code will work.  It does not pull directly from the clipboard, like `%paste`.  So if you do `%cpaste` `<ctrl/cmd-V>`, then you will be pasting the content from your local buffer.

Answer (score 4):

Not a brilliant solution, but I think this will work:

Use `%autoindent` to turn off autoindenting, type `if True:` and press enter. Then paste your indented code.

I think it should be possible to write an IPython extension to handle this better. I'll try to get round to looking into it. I've made [an issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/995).

If you use IPython a lot, you may want to get the new kernel/client architecture working - it should be possible to tunnel the connections over SSH, so you can use the Qt console on your local machine, talking to a kernel on a server. But that might take a bit of fiddling to get in place.

Comment: The reason regular pasting gets messed up is that it essentially simulates typing each character through the terminal.  It is impossible to detect whether this is real typing or pasting, so IPython will autoindent a line, then your pasted indentation comes in after that.  This will just be extra indentation if your paste is two lines, but it will actually be incorrect in most cases.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  It's not quite a solution, but acknowledgement that this is a bug (or at least can be thought of as such) is enough.  For now I'll stick with the workaround you provided.